# Map key to paste and immediately select

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I know I can select pasted text using [this trick](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Selecting_your_pasted_text) mapped to `gp`.

That means if I paste and then want to select the pasted block, I need to say `p` and `gp`.

I want to paste and immediately select that, ideally with `P`.

How can I achieve that?

Will I mess anything up if I rebind `P`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
nnoremap P p`[v`]
```

Doing this you will not "mess" anything but you will loose the ability to put the text from the register before the cursor (which is what `P` does by default).

To avoid loosing `P` you could also use

```
nnoremap P P`[v`]
nnoremap p p`[v`]
```

This way you will still get the put before and after cursor behavior but you will also always select the text put.

Comment: Similar mapping: Select last modified text block, `nnoremap gV `[v`]` or `nnoremap <expr> gV '`[' . getregtype()[0] . '`]'`

Comment: @PeterRincker Pro tip: escape backticks inside inline code blocks with backslash to make them render properly: `nnoremap gV \`[v\`]` . Took me a while to figure this out. :)