# Comment out just-pasted text?

Tags: visual-mode

In vim, I would like to operate on the block of text I just pasted. How?

For example, I select a block of text using shift-V, yank and then paste it somewhere. I would then like to comment that text out (e.g. using `gc` from the popular comment plugins). What are the keys to ask vim to recall the previously pasted block?

Comment: related https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14675/map-key-to-paste-and-immediately-select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `gc` is an operator, like in [tpope/vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary), you can use the `:help ']` motion:

```
p
gc']
```

Rationale:

- putting (not "pasting") text counts as a change,
- after a `p` or `P`, the cursor is left on the first character of the first changed line, so you only have to cover the rest of the changed lines,
- you can move the cursor to the first changed line with `'[`,
- you can use `']` to move the cursor to the last changed line.